# Issue when concatenating mkvs using ffmpeg: How to set timestamps properly?

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp, concatenation, mkv

I've attempted to concatenate 2 mkv videos with ffmpeg, using the following commands:

```
ffmpeg -i file-01.mkv -f mpegts -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb file-01.mpeg.ts
ffmpeg -i file-02.mkv -f mpegts -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb file-02.mpeg.ts
ffmpeg -isync -i "concat:file-01.mpeg.ts|file-02.mpeg.ts" -f matroska
-c copy output.mkv
```

However, I receive the following error:

> [matroska @ 0x7fc72a000600] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
>   [matroska @ 0x7fc72a000600] Can't write packet with unknown timestamp
>   av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument

How do I go about setting the timestamps?

Comment: `-isync` was disabled some years ago. Remove it unless your ffmpeg is that old. Add `-fflags +genpts` before the `-i`

Comment: Thank you that, @Mulvya. I tried that using `-fflags +genpts` but received the same error about unset timestamps.

Comment: Does the result play fine?

Comment: Thanks, @Mulvya. The result plays, but the result is basically a renamed version of the first of the two mkvs.

Comment: Do the files have audio?

Comment: @Mulvya yes, the source files have audio.

Comment: And the other properties are the same? Resolution, framerate, codec profile?

Comment: @Mulvya yes, other properties are the same. See comparison of both files here: http://imgur.com/a/EDpZ4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily a solution, per se, but mkvmerge worked for me in the end. Was much simpler, too:

```
mkvmerge -o "merged.mkv" "file1.mkv" +"file2.mkv"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try these steps:

```
ffmpeg -i file-01.mkv -c copy -map v 01.mp4
ffmpeg -i file-02.mkv -c copy -map v 02.mp4
ffmpeg -i 01.mp4 -i file-01.mkv -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb file-01.mpeg.ts
ffmpeg -i 02.mp4 -i file-02.mkv -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb file-02.mpeg.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:file-01.mpeg.ts|file-02.mpeg.ts" -f matroska
-c copy output.mkv
```

Some H.264 streams have packets with no PTS values. FFmpeg has haphazard support for muxing these streams.

Comment: Still not working, @Mulvya. Same erros resulting in failed conversion:
`[matroska @ 0x7f869c000000] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[matroska @ 0x7f869c000000] Can't write packet with unknown timestamp
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
frame= 1143 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    8381kB time=00:00:45.60 bitrate=1505.7kbits/s speed= 667x   
video:7857kB audio:528kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!`

Comment: Upload the files.

Comment: I ended up using mkvmerge instead. Had no issues. Much simpler.